# PHP: creating a file with fopen() results in "cryptic" value in string, repeating with existing file works

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to save a long (>700.000 chars) string to a file on the server by using fopen().

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);
echo $content;
```

But somehow, this only results in the correct file contents when the file already exists.
If the file doesn't exist, it is created with "cryptic" content, that doesn't make any sense to me.
(While the echo of $content displays the correct values)

Example of the first few chars of the file:

> ‹­W_oÛ6N€}VÃÐ¨,Ë©“8µ téþ´ÈÖ¬ÍÐm/%ž$Ö4©‘”tè7ÛÛ¾ØŽ”

When I reload the script, the file already exists and the content is written correctly and echoed correctly as before.

This also works, when I create the file myself via FTP (no matter what content it has before, I tried "Hello" as well). As long as the file already exists, everything is fine.

Also very strange is the fact, that if I insert a var_dump to see, what the value of $content is at a specific point, the file is written with the correct content, but the echo returns the "cryptic" string.
The var_dump seems to always have the correct values.

I already tried to use nearly all different fopen() modes like 'wb', 'wb+', 'wt', 'wt+', 'xt', etc.
I checked paths, permissions and searched google all night long. No success.

This is freaking me out, since I just can't see what is wrong or what I miss to check.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you try using `file_put_contents($filename, $content);` and confirm the problem persists?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Post the entire contents of the script, just by looking at these few lines that you posted - we can't figure out what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use utf8_encode()

```
$content = utf8_encode("text dsdasasd"); 
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);
echo $content;
```